# How to securely get variables from a link?

Tags: php, security, session

Suppose a website `xyz.com` is showing ads from my ad network `example.com` using JavaScript code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/click.php?id=12345678'></script>
```

Which shows the ad as:

```
click.php
<a href="http://example.com/process.php?var1=var1&var2=var2">
<img src="http://example.com/ads/banner.png"/></a>
```

When the link is clicked it is taken to `process.php` where I add and subtract balance using some MySQL queries and then redirect to ad's URL.

```
process.php
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//invalid click
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']==null || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']==null) {
header("location: http://example.com");
exit;
}
```

I want to add to an Unique Session at `click.php` and retrieve it at `process.php` to prevent invalid clicks. How do I do that?

**Update:** 
The answer below solves half of the issue but the users are still  able to send fake clicks using iframe and img tag as below:

```
<img src="http://example.com/click.php?id=12345678" height="1px" width="1px"/>
```

These clicks are still being counted as the request are served by both the pages `click.php` and `process.php`

What's the solution for this?

Comment: Is click.php and process.php are on same location?

Comment: See [this guide to URL parameter encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php). You either want AEAD or, if "short URL length" is important, use a random string lookup instead of encryption. **[Don't use rand()](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution to the problem and it works perfectly:
EDIT:
I have found a solution:
To set the variables using sessions at `click.php` and sent it to `process.php` using a random number

```
click.php
$_SESSION["ip"]=$ip;
$_SESSION["ua"]=$ua;
$rand="".rand(1,9)."".rand(0,9)."".rand(0,9)."".rand(0,9)."".rand(0,9)."".rand(0,9)."";
$_SESSION["hash"]=$rand;
<a href="http://example.com/process.php?hash=$rand">
<img src="http://example.com/ads/banner.png"/></a>
```

and getting the values from the session at `process.php`

```
process.php
$hash=$_GET["hash"];
$ua=$_SESSION["ua"];
$ip=$_SESSION["ip"];
$rand=$_SESSION["hash"];

// Invalid Redirection Protection
if(($hash!=$rand) || ($ip!=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) || ($ua!=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
header("location: http://example.com");
session_destroy();
exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood your question, your goal is to ensure that any requests arriving at http://example.com/process.php were from links created by http://example.com/click.php

(note that this only means that anyone trying to subvert your system needs to fetch http://example.com/click.php and extract the relevant data before fetching http://example.com/process.php. It raises the bar a little but it is a long way from being foolproof).

PHP already has a very good sessions mechanism. It would be easy to adapt to propogation via a url embedded in the script output (since you can't rely on cookies being available). However as it depends on writing to storage, its not very scalable.

I would go with a token with a finite number of predictable good states (and a much larger number of bad states). That means using some sort of encryption. While a symmetric cipher would give the easiest model to *understand* it's more tricky to implement than a hash based model.

With the hash model you would hash the values you are already sending with a secret salt and include the hash in the request. Then at the receiving end, repeat the exercise and compared the generated hash with the sent hash.

To prevent duplicate submissions you'd need to use some other identifier in the request vars - a large random number, the client IP address, the time....

```
define('SALT','4387trog83754kla');

function mk_protected_url($url)
{
    $parts=parse_url($url);
    $args=parse_str($parts['query']);
    $args['timenow']=time();
    $args['rand']=rand(1000,30000);
    sort($args);
    $q=http_build_query($args);
    $args['hash']=sha1(SALT . $q);
    $q=http_build_query($args);
    return $parts['scheme'] . '://'
        .$parts['host'] . '/'
        .$parts['path'] . '?' . $q;
}

function chk_protected_url($url)
{
    $parts=parse_url($url);
    $args=parse_str($parts['query']);
    $hash=$args['hash'];
    unset($args['hash'];
    // you might also want to validate other values in the query such as the age
    $q=http_build_query($args);
    $check=sha1(SALT . $q);
    return ($hash === $check)
 }
```

Comment: I don't know what your definition of "secure" is nor how much capacity you need to provide. Using cookies like this without providing a notification is illegal in Europe.